# ZSH aliases not found

Tags: shell, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

When I open my `~/.zshrc` file and add `alias homestead=“cd ~/Homestead”`, I expect to be able to type `homestead` and be taken to the Homestead folder.

Instead I get the following error:

`zsh: command not found: “cd`

Even when I use single quotes, i.e. `alias homestead='cd ~/Homestead'` and run `source ~/.zshrc` I get the same error.

*UPDATE: Also, when I run `which homestead` I get `homestead: aliased to "cd`*

How can I fix this?

Comment: is `source ~./zshrc` a typo? Did you mean `source ~/.zshrc` ?

Comment: Yep it is. Corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to open `~/.zshrc` in Sublime Text as opposed to TextEdit and to check that the `"` were coming up as `042` in an octal dump.

Comment: The heavier the editor - the more problems you'll encounter. Gedit rocks :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define this alias at all in `zsh`. Add the following to your `.zshrc`:

```
setopt autocd
cdpath+=(~)
```

The first allows you to treat a directory name as a command, which implicitly sets the working directory of the current shell to the named directory. The second specifies that if the current directory doesn't have a directory whose name is used with `cd` (or by itself with `autocd` set), then try to find it in a directory named in the `cdpath` parameter.

With these two, simply typing `Homestead` will first try to run a command named `Homestead`; failing that, it tries to `cd` to `./Homestead`, and failing *that*, will finally succeed in `cd`ing to `~/Homestead`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your locale settings is auto correcting a double quote " into a localized double quote “ as you posted. Since this is not recognized as a valid quote in shell, a simple white-space would break the string. So the actual alias is `“cd`.

As to why `alias homestead='cd ~/Homestead'` does not work, it seems you changed the alias in `~/.zshrc`. From the `which homestead` result, it can be seen that `alias homestead='cd ~/Homestead'` does not really work. Maybe there is another line of `alias homestead=“cd ~/Homestead”` hidden in `.zshrc` after it.

Comment: Maybe. I've updated my question to be more explicit. How can I fix this?

Comment: @BarryBlade, you can run `which homestead` to see what is actually executed.

Comment: I've added the output of which homestead to my main question

Comment: @BarryBlade, what is the output of executing `alias homestead='cd ~/Homestead'`?

Comment: @BarryBlade, so how could it still show `homestead: aliased to "cd`?

Comment: How the hell do I know? That's why I asked the question. Really non value adding comment from you

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes must be ASCII, not Unicode outside the ASCII range. Load the file in your editor, disable any automatic mangling of single quotes and double quotes.  Then replace the funny quotes with ASCII quotes `"` (code decimal 34, hex 22, octal 042). Or type the command at a prompt, then cut & paste it in your editor. If all else fails, add the alias at the end of your `.zshrc` with

```
printf 'alias homestead="cd ~/homestead"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Verify the result with octal dump,

```
od -bc .zshrc
```

The number above the quotes should appear as `042`.

Answer (score 0):

Just saying that for me what fixed it was an error in the first alias in my list that had a question mark in it.

Just switched to Mac OS Catalina and `~/.bashrc` to `~/.zshrc` and I guess zsh doesn't support question marks.

Maybe it'll help someone coming here from Google search like I did.